# Add space in NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Basically, I have a share button that pulls up a compose email modal view. I want to add a tab space in my NSStringWithFormat. Lets call it "postText". When I try to set a space like this:

`NSString *postText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\tHello, World! %@",myPointer];`

it doesn't insert anything (It returns "Hello, World! myPointerValue"), and if I just use tab, it messes up the spacing because I need to use tab about 10-20 times. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Side note - why are you using `stringWithFormat:`? Just do: `NSString *postText = @"\tHello, World!";`

Comment: @rmaddy: oops sorry, forgot to add pointer values into the string.

Comment: Is `myPointer` a reference to an object?

Comment: Clarify the problem. What do you mean "it doesn't insert anything"? Your resulting string should be a tab, then "Hello, World!", a space, then whatever `myPointer` equals.

Comment: Is a tab not just 4 spaces? Just add them in manually? @"    Hello, World!"

Comment: @random: I'm composing an email and I need around 20 %@'s and I tried inserting spaces myself but it was getting messy and confusing. I wanted to see if \t was correct. No idea why it isn't working.

Comment: Post the code where you are displaying the NSString.

Comment: Tabs do not equal space glyphs. The width of a tab depends on what is doing the layout.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `stringByPaddingToLength` function to add spaces anywhere in string. Check following sample function for the same.

```
-(NSString*)stringByAddingSpace:(NSString*)stringToAddSpace spaceCount:(NSInteger)spaceCount atIndex:(NSInteger)index{
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[@" " stringByPaddingToLength:spaceCount withString:@" " startingAtIndex:0],stringToAddSpace];
    return result;
}
```

Sample usage in your case:

```
NSString *spaceAddedText = [self stringByAddingSpace:@"Hello World!" spaceCount:5 atIndex:0]
NSString *postText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",spaceAddedText,myPointer];
```

Comment: does it still work in obj-c?